# Validate Azure B2C tokens with symmetric HS256 secrets

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to validate the signature of the tokens that were signed by B2C with a symmetric key using the HS256 algorithm. I have the tokens but I can't figure out what is used as a secret to encrypt/decrypt the signature. These tokens were stored for audit and many are already expired.

In a B2C environment what is used to generate symmetric signed tokens? How do I retrieve such information from the Azure Portal? Any ideas on how I could get this key or use a library such as MSAL to validate the signature of the tokens (note that the tokens might be expired)?

**More info:**

When I open the `jwks_uri` URL from the `openid-configuration` it prints the following information

```
{
   "keys": [
      {
         "kid": "mykidgoeshere",
         "use": "sig",
         "kty": "oct"
      }
   ]
}
```

And the header of the JWT contains

```
{
   "typ": "JWT",
   "alg": "HS256",
   "kid": "mykidgoeshere"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these special tokens or the standard ones?

To validate the standard ones, just use the B2C well-known endpoint to get the public keys. See [here](https://medium.com/medialesson/verify-signature-of-aad-b2c-jwt-tokens-in-jwt-io-63222a69ece6).

MSAL will validate the JWT or else look [here](https://jwt.io/libraries).